Topology for generating static high voltage
I need to generate a high voltage that will be used to charge up a small metal part, and keep it continually charged at a high voltage. The potential output voltage range should be from 0.5 - 40 kV, with a maximum current output of 0.1 mA. The application will also be quite volume restrained, so I need to prioritize miniaturizing the circuit (i.e., large transformers is out of the question). The space available will be a box approx. 40x50x100 mm. The system the circuit will be powered from is a 24 V system, so that's my starting point.
With these inputs I did some digging around and have started thinking about potential topologies/methods to accomplish this, but I'm not at all experienced with this kind of high voltage design (before anyone starts worrying about the safety aspects, I am in the process of reaching out to a professional that can help me with this design since it can be both difficult & potentially dangerous, but I want to be able to fact-check the professional to some degree).
The potential solution I came up with was using a Cockcroft-Walton multiplier circuit, but I'm both unsure of how to be able to have control of the output from the CW multiplier, but also on the feasibility of the idea. To be able to get such a high output from the CW multiplier I assume that I will need to already maximize the input voltage to the multiplier, so the first part of my circuit would be a DC/DC boost circuit that would take the voltage as high as reasonably possible (maybe 1 kV?). That DC voltage would then simply be shifted into a square wave signal, which is then fed into the CW multiplier, which would then need 20 stages to reach an output voltage of 40 kV, if my understanding is correct. This idea is already starting to sound somewhat unreasonable to me, but I'm wondering what people with more experience & knowledge thinks.
Is this a reasonable method to accomplish the design?
If so, how would I achieve good control of the output voltage? If I only control the input voltage of the CW multiplier I will get quite poor dynamic range of the output voltage right, since any error in the input voltage to the CW multiplier would get multiplied?
Is there a vastly easier/more convenient method to achieve?


Key information missing is: how much power do you need? (Shahriar of TSP recently had a 40kV amplifier teardown)

Ah yes, sorry, my bad! I'm not entirely sure, but I believe that 0.1 mA of current output, i.e., 4W should be enough. Maybe even less but I'm still trying to determine this.

CW multipliers work fine with voltages much greater than the forward diode drop - as is in your case. A simple topology would be a push-pull converter driven with a 24V square wave, with a 1:42 turns ratio. That gives about 1kV square wave on the output, which then goes into an encapsulated CW multiplier.
Doing a boost to 1000VDC is not efficient, since the boost topology is already switching, so by going to DC then back to AC is a waste.
The 1kV source needs a 5mA rating, since the 40x CW multiplier will take a bit over 4mA of much average current with 0.1mA on the output.
The 8mA 40kHz transformer would be fairly small, as would be the multiplier. The transformer will be custom-wound on a standard bobbin most likely. The bobbin will have sectioned secondary to keep the size down and not use additional inter-layer isolation for the secondary. If you asked me who to order it from, I'd go straight to https://feryster.pl and talk to them. You can also wind your own transformer on their EEL16-K-H-10P-8S transformer kit. It looks like this:
 
The capacitors in the multiplier will need to be rated at say 2x peak voltage on the 1kV square wave output. So 1.5kV or 2kV capacitors are needed.

Thank you for the reply!
How come you recommend a push-pull topology over either a flyback or a half-bridge? When I'm reading up on the different topologies it seems like push-pull has less requirements on the transformer compared to a flyback, but that half-bridge has similar transformer requirements compared to push-pull? And this app note from TI for example recommends flyback over push-pull or half-bridge when the load is <150W, due to the simplicity of a flyback (https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva603/snva603.pdf).

@LarsPetersson The arguments for "simplicity" in TI's app-notes apply to high volume production mostly. At the moment, your engineering time is way more expensive than the prototype, so aim for something that's easiest to design. Push-pull and half-bridge are equivalent, so use whatever works best for you.

Ok, thank you!
Another question, you say that it's inefficient to boost the voltage to 1000VDC to then switch it to AC, which I understand and agree with, but how would you get a square wave output from a push-pull converter? I'm experimenting with simulating it in LTSpice, and the switch node before my LC filter seems fairly square, but if I remove the LC filter then everything becomes unstable. Shouldn't I be able to get a square wave output without the LC filter?
